# DateFormat returning wrong hour

Tags: java, time, hour, datetime-parsing

I am trying to parse the string `"20/08/18 13:21:00:428"` using the `DateFormat` class and a formatting pattern of `"dd/MM/yy' 'HH:mm:ss:SSS"`. The Timezone is set to BST.

The date returned for the above is correct but the time is getting returned as `08` for the hours instead of `13` - `"Mon Aug 20 08:21:00 BST 2018"`

The following snippet prints the date and time just mentioned:

```
    String toBeParsed = "20/08/18 13:21:00:428";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy' 'HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST"));
    Date parsedDate = format.parse(toBeParsed);
    System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

Is this something to do with my timezone or have I misunderstood the pattern?

Comment: please add the language tag

Comment: We could help you much better if you’d show the code that produced the unexpected result. Best in the form of [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like you are using the old-fashioned `Date` class? I recommend you avoid that. It is long outdated and was always poorly designed. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BST is Bangladesh Standard Time. The correct time zone to use is "Europe/London" if you want automatic summer time, or "UTC+1" if you want British Summer Time always.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu H:mm:ss:SSS");
    String toBeParsed = "20/08/18 13:21:00:428";
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(toBeParsed, formatter)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2018-08-20T13:21:00.428+01:00[Europe/London]

### What went wrong in your code?

While I always recommend against the long outdated and poorly designed classes `Date`,  `TimeZone` and `DateFormat`, in this case they are behaving particularly confusingly. Printing a `Date` on a JVM with Europe/London as default time zone gives time zone as `BST` if the date is in the summer time part of the year:

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    Date oldFashionedDate = new Date();
    System.out.println(oldFashionedDate);
```

> Mon Aug 20 15:45:39 BST 2018

However, when I give time zone as BST, Bangladesh time is understood, but it comes out with the non-standard abbreviation BDT:

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST"));
    System.out.println(oldFashionedDate);
```

> Mon Aug 20 20:45:39 BDT 2018

(I have observed this behaviour on Java 8 and Java 10.)

Another lesson to learn is never to rely on three and four letter time zone abbreviations. They are ambiguous and not standardized.

- BST may mean Brazil Summer Time or Brazilian Summer Time, Bangladesh Standard Time, Bougainville Standard Time or British Summer Time (note that S is sometimes for Standard, sometimes for Summer, which is typically the opposite of Standard Time).
- BDT may mean Brunei Darussalam Time or British Daylight Time (another name for British Summer Time (BST)), but I wasn’t aware that Bangladesh Time was also sometimes abbreviated this way.

PS Thanks to DodgyCodeException for spotting the time zone abbreviation interpretation issue.

### Link

[Time Zone Abbreviations — Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)